# How to create a column based on size of a set in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in pandas and I'm using 'set' as an aggregate function in a groupby and I create the following dataframe

```
A, B, C
1, 2, {nan, v}
1, 3, {nan, v,b}
```

In this example `A` and `B` are the columns I used in the groupby. I'd like to add another column to this dataframe which is the number of elements in column `C` which are not ``nan. That is I want my dataframe to look like below

```
A, B, C, D
1, 2, {nan, v}, 1
1, 3, {nan, v,b}, 2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It is better upvote and accept to close the old question before you asking a new one, I notice , you have been asking a lot question with good answer posted but none of them had been accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
df['D']=pd.DataFrame(df.C.tolist(),index=df.index).notnull().sum(axis=1)
```